# Placing Hotels having same Geo-Coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing a problem that in a teretorry I have to display 6 Hotels with info windows but the problem is that all having the same geo coordinates.
Is there a way that despite having the same coordinates all are visible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the hotel coordinates (latitude/longitude) are from a different API like expedia or so.. The hotel APIs sometimes provide only area coordinates.
I would try to solve the problem by the address and not by the coordinates. Just get the hotel address from the hotel API and use Google Maps Api to show the hotels by that address.

Answer (score 0):

If that isn't an area coordinate you can use a special marker as a placeholder and print all information in the infowindow.